# How to enter passcode created with Greek characters once the Greek keyboard has been disabled?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, remote-control, unlock, security

I have an iPhone 4s with iOS 7 and I entered a passcode with Greek letters, then I removed the Greek keyboard and now my iPhone is locked. I can't unlock it because the Greek keyboard isn't there any more. Is there a way to unlock my iPhone without restoring it?

I think it would be possible if I could remotely control my iPhone on PC and enter the passcode with my PC keyboard because I have Greek letters on my PC keyboard, so is there any software for remote control without jailbreak?

Comment: If you hold your finger on the key it offers you altenate characters. Nit put this as an answer yet as I do not know if any of tbem are the same as greek

Comment: @markhunte looks like accented Latin characters only

Comment: Does your keyboard have a small globe icon on it. If so you can click that to change languages.